# Put two legends in two rows

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

The following

```
data(iris)
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) +
  geom_point(aes(shape = Species, colour = Petal.Width)) + 
  theme(legend.position = 'bottom')
```

puts the two legends `Petal.Width` and `Species` at the bottom side by side.

Can I also put them on top of each other like so?

[image: Example]

I know this is possible with `cowplot` but is there also another way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It can be done by adjusting `legend.box` inside `theme()`, for example

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) +
    geom_point(aes(shape = Species, colour = Petal.Width)) + 
    theme(
        legend.justification = 'left', 
        legend.position = 'bottom', legend.box = 'vertical', 
        legend.box.just = 'left')
```

[image]

**Edit**

There are a number of parameters that can be passed to `theme()` to fine tune spacing and margins between legends and between the plot and the legends, e.g. (copying from `?theme`)

- `legend.margin` controls the margin around each legend
- `legend.box.margin` controls the margin around the area containing all legends
- `legend.spacing`, `legend.spacing.x`, `legend.spacing.y` control spacing between legends

In your case, if your goal is to bring legends closer together vertically, you can try e.g. `legend.margin = margin(-5, 0, 0, 0)`

Comment: Brilliant! Any way to reduce the space between the two legends?

Comment: @Pascal  It's possible by playing with other parameters of `theme()` - have a look at my edit

Comment: Perfect. Thanks!